¿Cómo enlazar con jQuery desde un HTML a js?
Estoy intentando utilizar jquery en los siguientes programas, pero aunque creo que la implementación es correcta (no la he podido probar), no se como puedo hacer para poder utilizar jQuery. ¿Existe alguna etiqueta especial?
Ejercicio Alumnos:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alumnos.css">
</head>
<body>
   
    <h1>Listado de Alumnos y Notas Finales</h1>

    <form id="module-form">
        <label for="module-select">Elige un módulo:</label>
        <select id="module-select" name="module-select">
            <option value="dwec">DWEC</option>
            <option value="dwes">DWES</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Mostrar Alumnos</button>
    </form>

    <table id="alumnos-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Alumno</th>
                <th>Nota Práctica</th>
                <th>Nota Teórica</th>
                <th>Nota Final</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Los datos se cargarán aquí -->
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="suspensos-count">
        <!-- El contador de suspensos se mostrará aquí -->
    </div>

    
    <script src="js/alumnos.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#module-form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        const selectedModule = $('#module-select').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: './archivos/alumnos.json', // Actualiza esta ruta al archivo JSON
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                const alumnos = data[selectedModule];
                let suspensosCount = 0;

                const tableBody = $('#alumnos-table tbody');
                tableBody.empty();

                alumnos.forEach(alumno => {
                    const notaFinal = (alumno.practico + alumno.teorico) / 2;
                    if (notaFinal < 5) {
                        suspensosCount++;
                    }

                    const row = `
                        <tr>
                            <td>${alumno.alumno}</td>
                            <td>${alumno.practico}</td>
                            <td>${alumno.teorico}</td>
                            <td>${notaFinal.toFixed(2)}</td>
                        </tr>
                    `;

                    tableBody.append(row);
                });

                $('#suspensos-count').text(`Número de suspensos: ${suspensosCount}`);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error al cargar los datos del archivo JSON.');
            }
        });
    });
});




En Internet escribir en mayúsculas se considera gritar. Por favor no escribas todo el texto en mayúsculas.

jQuery es una biblioteca de javascript, que está contenida en un archivo. Necesitas agregar ese script para que cargue con tu página. Después de la línea dónde se carga, ya puedes usar la biblioteca, usualmente a través de $.
Mira la etiqueta <script> en el siguiente ejemplo:


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contenido').html("Hola mundo!");
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenido">Cargando...</div>



Usualmente añades esa etiqueta dentro del <head> de tu página. Puedes tener tu propia copia del script para cargarla desde tu servidor, o enlazar alguna disponible públicamente, como esta de cloudflare que estoy enlazando en la respuesta.

La forma de usar jQuery es como usar un script de alguna biblioteca Js.
Una opción es descargar la biblioteca y utilizar sus recursos desde el siguiente enlace:
https://jquery.com/download/
Guarda el archivo en una carpeta y especifica la ruta.
Nombre de la carpeta: "script"
script/jquery-3.7.1.min.js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      
         <script src="script/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
          <script src="script/script.js" defer></script>             
    </head>
    
    <body>

La segunda opción es utilizar una Red de Distribución de Contenido (CDN, por sus siglas en inglés)
https://releases.jquery.com/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           <script src="script/script.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>

Para referencia y demostración de uso:
Usando la abreviación para el evento $(document).ready(...):
$(function(){
  // Todo el código jQuery
});

En jQuery, todo comienza con "$", los métodos empiezan con "$" para tener acceso desde el objeto global.
Ejemplo:
Loop en JavaScript puro:


for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log('=> ' + i);
}



Usando jQuery:


$.each(Array.from({ length: 5 }), function(index) {
    console.log('=> ' + index);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



$.each() es un método de jQuery.
* Para más información y detalles, consulta la documentación oficial.
